# How to define a taxonomy of non associative operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, binary-operations, associativity

Let $A$ be a set, and let $a,b,c\in A$. Let also $\circ: A\times A\rightarrow A$ be a binary operation on $A$. We agree as usual to write $a\circ b$ to mean $\circ(a,b)$.

We say that $\circ$ is associative if for any $a,b,c\in A$ the following holds:
\begin{equation}
(a\circ b)\circ c=a\circ (b\circ c)
\end{equation}
That's OK, but given three elements in $A$ there are many ways to compose them. In particular, we can compute the following $12$ compositions:
\begin{equation}
(a\circ b)\circ c\qquad\qquad
a\circ (b\circ c)\\
(a\circ c)\circ b\qquad\qquad
a\circ (c\circ b)\\
(b\circ a)\circ c \qquad\qquad
b\circ (a\circ c) \\
(b\circ c) \circ a \qquad\qquad
b\circ (c \circ a) \\
(c\circ a)\circ b \qquad\qquad
c\circ (a\circ b) \\
(c\circ b)\circ a \qquad\qquad
c\circ (b\circ a)
\end{equation}
They are of course $12$ because we are permuting $3$ objects and for each permutation we have $2$ ways of putting meaningful parentheses, so $3!\cdot 2 = 12$. Associativity means that we identify the first (top left) object with the second (top right); this has a strong meaning to us because usual number fields ($\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$) behave in this way.

My question is: what happens if we identify the first relation with a different one taken from the other $11$? Are there some relevant (i.e. studied in literature) examples of such structures? The only examples I could find of non associative structures like this are defined over more complex objects, for example the cross product on $\mathbb{R}^3$ or generally a Lie bracket is not associative but is defined over a vector space. I don't even know what exactly to search for to organise my thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one drops the identity and associativity axioms from the definition of group, we get the definition of a *[quasigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup)*, and if we retain the identity axiom, the structure is called a *loop*. A priori these need not satisfy any further composition conditions, but some well-known nonassociative quasigroups do satisfy such conditions.

For example, the loop $\mathbb{O} - \{0\}$ of nonzero octonions (under multiplication) satisfies the *Moufang identity*:
$$(a \circ b) \circ (c \circ a) = a \circ ((b \circ c) \circ a),$$
and we call loops that satisfy this identity *[Moufang loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_loop)*. All Moufang loops are *alternative*, which means that any subloop generated by two elements is associative, or equivalently, that $a \circ a \circ b, a \circ b \circ a, b \circ a \circ a$ are all unambiguous. (One can just as well ask for these identities to hold for a $k$-algebra.

As for Lie algebras (including the cross product on $\mathbb{R}^3$), they too satisfy a composition condition (which we can rearrange to via as a product rule for the map $a \circ \, \cdot \,$) called the *Jacobi identity*:
$$a \circ (b \circ c) + b \circ (c \circ a) + c \circ (a \circ b) = 0.$$

Probably without some additional hypotheses there is no sensible "taxonomy" of algebras satisfying another one of your other 10 quasi-associativity axiom (just for color, the number of general quasigroups of order $n$ [grows very fast](http://oeis.org/A057991) with $n$). Some of them lead to interesting conditions that can be described intuitively. For example, the condition $$(a \circ b) \circ c = c \circ (a \circ b)$$ just says that $\text{im } \circ$ is contained in the center of $(A, \circ)$; if $(A, \circ)$ is a quasigroup, then $\text{im }\circ = A$, so in that case the condition is equivalent to commutativity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what are $a,b,c$ and $x,y,z$?

Comment: I accidentally submitted before the reply was complete, the finished reply probably answers your question, but let me know if not.

Comment: Thank you again. Actually the Lie algebra example doesn't really answer the question because I am searching for simpler objects, i.e. sets with just one binary operation.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. For any Lie algebra, you can always keep just the bracket relation and discard the underlying vector space operations.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how can you discard the underlying vector space addition in defining the Jacobi identity?

Comment: You can't, but some interesting features of Lie algebras (e.g., nilpotence, solvability) depend only on the bracket operation itself.

Comment: What to add to this brilliant answer? You may be interested in _quasi-associativity axioms_ that descend from studying quasigroups' **parastrophes** (definition 2 in  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1804.pdf). Quasigroups with some additional properties equal some of their parastrophes, the first example that comes to my mind is that for all commutative quasigroups $(a\circ b)\circ c=(b\circ a)\circ c$ holds.

Comment: @MattAllegro you already added something to the (already good!) answer :)

Comment: Quasigroups parastrophes, also: http://www.mathnet.ru/links/468f3db305a2df3c43c7b73b1276e9d6/basm61.pdf

Comment: @Travis Just a small note: *alternative* usually refers to (left alternative) $a\circ (a\circ b) = (a\circ a) \circ b$ and (right alternative) $(b\circ a)\circ a = b\circ (a\circ a)$.  The usual term for any subloop generated by two elements is a subgroup is usual referred to as *diassociative*.  It is somewhat confusing if you are looking at alternative rings that give a multiplicative structure that is a Moufang loop.